# (Java) Why is a HashSet allowed to be used synchronously if it is non synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, hashset, synchronous

I've been reading up on the differences between a `HashMap`, `HashSet`, and `HashTable`. A key thing I've been noticing is that I've seen that `HashMap`/`HashSet` are not synchronized while a `HashTable` is.

However in a code base that I've seen before there are several places where a block like this is used:

```
synchronized (hashSet) {
    //Some code involving the hashset 
}
```

How is this possible if a `HashSet` isn't synchronized? Does the synchronized block simply allow us to use a non synchronous data structure as if it were synchronized?

If `HashSet` were synchronized would we just not have to include the synchronized() {} block?

Comment: `synchronized` just requires a reference to some object, from which it obtains a monitor.  It doesn't matter what that object is.

Comment: Yes, the synchronized block, if used consistently, allows you to use a non-synchronized object as if it were synchronized.

Comment: It is important to understand that you can use `synchronized(object)` for an arbitrary object, but it has only an impact to all threads using `synchronized` *on the same object*. Threads synchronizing on a different object or not using `synchronized` are unaffected, so if these threads access the `HashSet`, the application is still broken. You can make any access to any data structure thread safe, if you’re using the synchronization technique *consistently*.

Comment: @Holger Thank you! That essentially answers my question. So if we used a synchronized data structure instead, would we be able to do the same thing but without synchronized blocks?

Comment: as a side note there is `ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet()`

Comment: @Omar Samara: well, if you do something like `if(!set.contains(obj)) add(obj);`, it doesn’t help if both methods are `synchronized`, as having two thread safe calls does not prevent a potential change in-between (this is a logical error known as “check-then-act” anti-pattern). So it’s not unusual that for certain application logic, having all-`synchronized` methods in the underlying data structure is not enough, you might still need an explicit lock/`synchronized`. That’s why today, the usual pattern is to only have explicit application-specific locking rather than all-`synchronized` methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `synchronized` block requires some object to syncronize upon. When a `HashSet` is said to be unsynchronized it just means that it's methods aren't synchronized in their own right, and if you intend to use it in a multi-threaded context, you should handle synchronization by yourself (e.g., by `synchronizing` on the `HashSet` object as shown in your snippet).

Comment: So what's the significance of using a synchronized data structure? If say we used a HashTable (since it is synchronized), would we be able to do the exact same thing but as what we did with the synchronized block but without using the synchronized block?

Comment: You could of course `synchronize` on a `Hashtable`, just like any other object. But note that the only thing guaranteed by using a synchronized data structure is that it's basic operations (like `put` and `get`) won't break in  a multithreaded context. You may very well need to use some synchronization method yourself to ensure that your higher order logic works properly.